# How to restrict users from viewing not more than 2 level Account Hierarchy

Tags: account, configuration, hierarchy

What configuration changes should be made so that a user should be able to view 2 level account hierarchy after he/she clicks on Hierarchy Icon?

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me. Are you trying to prevent users from _creating_ more than two levels of hierarchy, prevent users from _viewing_ more than two levels of hierarchy, or change fields shown on the Account Hierarchy view? Please [edit].

Comment: @DavidReed - Thank you for pointing this out, I realise now that my question is not framed properly. Now for the clarification I want to prevent users from viewing not more than 2 level Account Hierarchy.